# Shift operator in C prepends ones instead of zeros

Tags: c, types, binary, bit-shift

Here is the code:

```
#define u8 char
#define u32 unsigned int

typedef struct {
    //decoded instruction fields
    u8 cond; // Condition (f.ex. 1110 for always true)
    u8 instruction_code; // Is a constant since we only use branch
    u32 offset; // Offset from current PC
} dcdinst;

u8 mem[1024];

mem[0x0] = 0b11101010;

u8* instruction_addr = &mem[pc];

if (instruction_addr == NULL) {
    return false;
}

unsigned int first_part = instruction_addr[0];

// Here is the code that presents a problem:
// I try to get the upper part of the first byte
inst.cond = first_part >> 4;
```

`first_part` is the following byte: 11101010.
`inst.cond` becomes 11111110, but I need it to be 00001110.

So, my actual problem is that I want to get the first 4 bits of my instruction which starts at the address `instruction_addr`. I tried to do so by using the right shift operator `>>` but the problem is that instead of prepending 0s to the left of the byte, it prepends 1s.

I found on stackoverflow that I first had to cast the value to a unsigned one, and that's what I did by using the variable `first_part`, but I still have the same problem. I don't understand why the shift seems to "see" my variable as a negative one while its type is specifically "unsigned".

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Could you please reduce this to a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that people don't have to sticth together six bits of code in their head?

Comment: I don't see why you have `#define u8 char` and not `#define u8 unsigned char`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Or better, `typedef unsigned char u8;`, so the compiler knows the association, not just the preprocessor.

Comment: Why do you assume `char` is unsigned`? And why not use `stdint.h` fixed width types, but homebrew types?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I compressed everything. Hope it's ok now.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was it, thank you !

Comment: @Olaf I did not assume such thing. I even tried to do `first_part = first_part >> 4`  and then `inst.cond = first_part` but I still had the same problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't change the question to a solution, I just deleted some parts of my code and some sentences I had written, but there was still the question with the same problem in the code

Comment: @WeatherVane First comment specifically asked me to make a more concise question. I thought  that would be better even for future viewers of my question.

Comment: Sorry, restored (I hope) and deleted some comments

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `u8` type is using `char` without specifying signedness, which means it has undefined signedness. It's likely your compiler is using a `signed char` by default. Thus, you're subject to sign-extension during operations and during promotion.

Change:

```
#define u8 char
#define u32 unsigned int
```

to:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int u32;
```

(or use `stdint.h` types properly), and your storage should be actually unsigned.

Using `typedef`s also means the compiler is involved with this aliasing, it's not just a preprocessor text replacement, eliminating a class of subtle errors.

Comment: The best part is parenthesised.

Comment: Supporting @WeatherVane: Never use homebrew fixed-width types if there are standard types available.