# can't shift negative numbers to the right in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am going through 'The C language by K&R'. Right now I am doing the bitwise section. I am having a hard time in understanding the following code.

```
int mask = ~0 >> n;
```

I was playing on using this to mask n left side of another binary like this.
    0000 1111
    1010 0101 // random number

My problem is that when I print var mask it still negative -1. Assuming n is 4. I thought shifting ~0 which is -1 will be 15 (0000 1111).

thanks for the answers

Comment: This book has a strong reputation, but it is very old, and will lead you astray when dealing with modern (post-2005 or so) C compilers.

Comment: @zwol what book do you recommend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shift operator in C prepends ones instead of zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239906/shift-operator-in-c-prepends-ones-instead-of-zeros)

Comment: @TheCaptain I regret to say I do not have a recommendation for a newer book.  I learned C a very long time ago myself.

Answer (score 6):

Performing a right shift on a negative value yields an *implementation defined* value.  Most hosted implementations will shift in `1` bits on the left, as you've seen in your case, however that doesn't necessarily have to be the case.

Unsigned types as well as positive values of signed types always shift in `0` bits on the left when shifting right.  So you can get the desired behavior by using unsigned values:

```
unsigned int mask = ~0u >> n;
```

This behavior is documented in section 6.5.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *5* The result of **E1 >> E2** is **E**1 right-shifted **E2** bit positions.  If **E1** has an unsigned type or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative
>   value, the value of the result is the integral part  of  the  quotient
>   of **E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>** .If **E1** has  a  signed  type  and  a  negative  value,  the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: More precisely, it yields an implementation-defined value. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.7p5. (Implementation-defined *behavior* could permit it to do something other than yielding a value.)

Comment: implementation-defined values are unpredictable values?

Comment: @TheCaptain Implementation defined means that the C standard doesn't specify what the values must be, but the specific implementation (i.e. gcc, MSVC, etc.) must document what it does in that case.  If the values were unpredictable, that would be called either **indeterminate** or **unspecified** values.

Answer (score 3):

Right-shifting negative signed integers is an implementation-defined behavior, which is usually (but not always) filling the left with ones instead of zeros. That's why no matter how many bits you've shifted, it's always -1, as the left is always filled by ones.

When you shift unsigned integers, the left will always be filled by zeros. So you can do this:

```
unsigned int mask = ~0U >> n;
                      ^
```

You should also note that `int` is typically 2 or 4 bytes, meaning if you want to get 15, you need to right-shift 12 or 28 bits instead of only 4. You can use a `char` instead:

```
unsigned char mask = ~0U;
mask >>= 4;
```

Comment: what does the U mean and where can I read more about this topic? The book doesn't give very good details. There is no U at all.

Comment: @TheCaptain: A `U` suffix on an integer constant means that it's of an unsigned type, in this case specifically `unsigned int`.

Comment: @TheCaptain I think [C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Shift_operators) is a good site for reference. Look up that link and you'll find a detailed description about shift operators.

Comment: Right-shifting a negative signed integer yields an implementation-defined result.

Comment: @KeithThompson I realized that. See if the edit makes sense now.

Comment: Note that with 32-bit `int` and `n==0`, `int mask = ~0U >> n;` results in more implementation defined behavior of assigning an out-of-range `unsigned` to an `int`.  Using _unsigned_ types with shifts is much less complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In C, and many other languages, `>>` is (usually) an [*arithmetic* right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) when performed on *signed* variables (like `int`). This means that the new bit shifted in from the left is a copy of the previous most-significant bit (MSB). This has the effect of preserving the sign of a two's compliment negative number (and in this case the value).

This is in contrast to a [*logical* right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift), where the MSB is always replaced with a zero bit. This is applied when your variable is *unsigned* (e.g. `unsigned int`).

From Wikipeda:

> The >> operator in C and C++ is not necessarily an arithmetic shift. Usually it is only an arithmetic shift if used with a signed integer type on its left-hand side. If it is used on an unsigned integer type instead, it will be a logical shift.

In your case, if you plan to be working at a bit level (i.e. using masks, etc.) I would strongly recommend two things:

1. Use unsigned values.
2. Use types with specific sizes from `<stdint.h>` like `uint32_t`

Comment: Your change makes sense now :-)

Comment: Right-shifting a negative signed integer yields an implementation-defined result.